# Как настроить jest для поддержки export/import?

Tags: javascript, jest

Как я могу настроить конфигурацию jest, чтобы он поддерживал export/import?

Comment: Экспорт/импорт это как раз НЕ коммонджээс

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules

Comment: @AlexeyTen, ошибся, исправил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправил ошибку, путем добавления файла `.babelrc` в папку с тестами, в котором написал:

```
{
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Также установил пакет:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs
```